# Is it valid to parallelize Hmisc aregimpute?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, hmisc

I am trying to use Hmisc::aregimpute for multiple imputation of my dataset.  I would like to be able to spread the computation out over a number of cores.
I tried to create a function that would combine the output of two imputations as if it were the only one imputation.  Looking at the output aregImpute objects, it seems like only a few of the contained objects need to change.

```r
c_aregImpute <- function(areg1, areg2){
  call <- areg1$call
  call[["n.impute"]] <- areg1$n.impute + areg2$n.impute
  structure(list(call=call,
                 formula=areg1$formula,
                 match=areg1$match,
                 fweighted=areg1$fweighted,
                 pmmtype=areg1$pmmtype,
                 n=areg1$n,
                 p=areg1$p,
                 na=areg1$na,
                 nna=areg1$nna,
                 type=areg1$type,
                 tlinear=areg1$tlinear,
                 nk=areg1$nk,
                 cat.levels=areg1$cat.levels,
                 df=areg1$df,
                 n.impute=areg1$n.impute + areg2$n.impute,
                 imputed=mapply(cbind,areg1$imputed, areg2$imputed),
                 x=areg1$x,
                 rsq=areg2$rsq,
                 resampacc=areg1$resampacc),
            class='aregImpute')
}
```

My question is whether this is a valid way to combine aregImpute objects. If not, what are the pitfalls of this approach? Are there other solutions that use Hmisc::aregImpute?

```r
library("Hmisc")
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, round.POSIXt, trunc.POSIXt, units


#code from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.0-3/topics/aregImpute
set.seed(3)
x1 <- rnorm(200)
x2 <- x1^2
x3 <- runif(200)
m <- 30
x2[1:m] <- NA
a <- aregImpute(~x1+x2+I(x3), n.impute=50, nk=4, match='closest') # output clipped for SO
#> 
Iteration 50 
a
#> 
#> Multiple Imputation using Bootstrap and PMM
#> 
#> aregImpute(formula = ~x1 + x2 + I(x3), n.impute = 50, nk = 4, 
#>     match = "closest")
#> 
#> n: 200   p: 3    Imputations: 50     nk: 4 
#> 
#> Number of NAs:
#> x1 x2 x3 
#>  0 30  0 
#> 
#>    type d.f.
#> x1    s    3
#> x2    s    1
#> x3    l    1
#> 
#> Transformation of Target Variables Forced to be Linear
#> 
#> R-squares for Predicting Non-Missing Values for Each Variable
#> Using Last Imputations of Predictors
#>    x2 
#> 0.984


c_aregImpute <- function(areg1, areg2){
  call <- areg1$call
  call[["n.impute"]] <- areg1$n.impute + areg2$n.impute
  structure(list(call=call,
                 formula=areg1$formula,
                 match=areg1$match,
                 fweighted=areg1$fweighted,
                 pmmtype=areg1$pmmtype,
                 n=areg1$n,
                 p=areg1$p,
                 na=areg1$na,
                 nna=areg1$nna,
                 type=areg1$type,
                 tlinear=areg1$tlinear,
                 nk=areg1$nk,
                 cat.levels=areg1$cat.levels,
                 df=areg1$df,
                 n.impute=areg1$n.impute + areg2$n.impute,
                 imputed=mapply(cbind,areg1$imputed, areg2$imputed),
                 x=areg1$x,
                 rsq=areg2$rsq,
                 resampacc=areg1$resampacc),
            class='aregImpute')
}
a1 <- aregImpute(~x1+x2+I(x3), n.impute=25, nk=4, match='closest') # output clipped for SO
#> Iteration 25 
a2 <- aregImpute(~x1+x2+I(x3), n.impute=25, nk=4, match='closest') # output clipped for SO
#> Iteration 25 
ca <- c_aregImpute(a1, a2)
a$rsq 
#>        x2 
#> 0.9841747
a1$rsq
#>        x2 
#> 0.9721295
a2$rsq
#>        x2 
#> 0.9787526
ca$rsq
#>        x2 
#> 0.9787526
a
#> 
#> Multiple Imputation using Bootstrap and PMM
#> 
#> aregImpute(formula = ~x1 + x2 + I(x3), n.impute = 50, nk = 4, 
#>     match = "closest")
#> 
#> n: 200   p: 3    Imputations: 50     nk: 4 
#> 
#> Number of NAs:
#> x1 x2 x3 
#>  0 30  0 
#> 
#>    type d.f.
#> x1    s    3
#> x2    s    1
#> x3    l    1
#> 
#> Transformation of Target Variables Forced to be Linear
#> 
#> R-squares for Predicting Non-Missing Values for Each Variable
#> Using Last Imputations of Predictors
#>    x2 
#> 0.984
ca
#> 
#> Multiple Imputation using Bootstrap and PMM
#> 
#> aregImpute(formula = ~x1 + x2 + I(x3), n.impute = 50, nk = 4, 
#>     match = "closest")
#> 
#> n: 200   p: 3    Imputations: 50     nk: 4 
#> 
#> Number of NAs:
#> x1 x2 x3 
#>  0 30  0 
#> 
#>    type d.f.
#> x1    s    3
#> x2    s    1
#> x3    l    1
#> 
#> Transformation of Target Variables Forced to be Linear
#> 
#> R-squares for Predicting Non-Missing Values for Each Variable
#> Using Last Imputations of Predictors
#>    x2 
#> 0.979
matplot(x1[1:m]^2, ca$imputed$x2)
```

[image]

```r
matplot(x1[1:m]^2, a$imputed$x2)
```

[image]

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info --------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/New_York            
#>  date     2017-08-08
#> Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package      * version date       source         
#>  acepack        1.4.1   2016-10-29 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  backports      1.0.5   2017-01-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  base64enc      0.1-3   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  checkmate      1.8.2   2016-11-02 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  cluster        2.0.5   2016-10-08 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  colorspace     1.3-2   2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  data.table     1.10.4  2017-02-01 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  devtools       1.12.0  2016-12-05 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  digest         0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  evaluate       0.10    2016-10-11 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  foreign        0.8-67  2016-09-13 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  Formula      * 1.2-1   2015-04-07 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  ggplot2      * 2.2.1   2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  gridExtra      2.2.1   2016-02-29 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  gtable         0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  Hmisc        * 4.0-2   2016-12-31 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  htmlTable      1.9     2017-01-26 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  htmltools      0.3.6   2017-04-28 cran (@0.3.6)  
#>  htmlwidgets    0.8     2016-11-09 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  knitr          1.15.1  2016-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  lattice      * 0.20-34 2016-09-06 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  latticeExtra   0.6-28  2016-02-09 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  lazyeval       0.2.0   2016-06-12 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  magrittr       1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  Matrix         1.2-8   2017-01-20 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  memoise        1.0.0   2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  munsell        0.4.3   2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  nnet           7.3-12  2016-02-02 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  plyr           1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  RColorBrewer   1.1-2   2014-12-07 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  Rcpp           0.12.12 2017-07-15 cran (@0.12.12)
#>  rlang          0.1.1   2017-05-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  rmarkdown      1.3     2016-12-21 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  rpart          4.1-10  2015-06-29 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  rprojroot      1.2     2017-01-16 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  scales         0.4.1   2016-11-09 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  stringi        1.1.5   2017-04-07 cran (@1.1.5)  
#>  stringr        1.2.0   2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  survival     * 2.40-1  2016-10-30 CRAN (R 3.3.2) 
#>  tibble         1.3.3   2017-05-28 cran (@1.3.3)  
#>  withr          2.0.0   2017-07-28 cran (@2.0.0)  
#>  yaml           2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
```

Comment: Can you provide some intro to what `Hmisc::aregImpute` does?

Comment: I don't understand the full depth of `Hmisc::aregImpute`, but from what I understand it does multiple imputation of missing values. See documentation for more detail: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.0-3/topics/aregImpute

Comment: For me, multiple imputation is just generating multiple datasets with some randomness between imputations. So this should be embarrassingly parallel.

Comment: "`aregImpute` takes all aspects of uncertainty in the imputations into account by using the bootstrap to approximate the process of drawing predicted values from a full Bayesian predictive distribution. Different bootstrap resamples are used for each of the multiple imputations" -- this sounds computationally expensive. If your data set were a few gigabytes in size, I would imagine this may take hours.

Comment: @F.Privé, multiple imputation is a statistical procedure. You can't just generate random data and shove it in. The theory behind aregImpute is that it's trying to compute the conditional distribution of each missing value given some parameters. It can be parallelized, but it's not "embarrasingly" simple to parallelize this processes.

Comment: What is the main computation in this process?

Comment: @F.Privé, there does not seem to be one 'main' step that is computationally expensive step, but rather multiple conditional steps: 1. multiple bootstraps, 2. density estimation, 3. imputation/prediction. It is also not clear if the current imputation is conditional on the previous, e.g. imputed valued from the first order of variables is also used in density estimation of the next order of variables. Also, if the data set is large, parallel might drain memory which would lead another wall to climb.

Comment: To answer OP's question, is it valid to parallelize this step? Maybe. Depends on the methodology of imputation. Can OP summarize the steps taken in imputation?

Comment: Another question for OP is why this specific tool? It seems that there are many imputation methods out there, some more simple than others. Is there any real marginal benefit to this method other than its fanciness? How does this method compare to simple mean/median imputation, or kNN?